# Compile error method constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

I have an array list `hand` that has to stay private in Class A. In class B, I have a method `public String checkHand(ArrayList<Card> hand)` This line has to stay the way it is. `checkHand` is supposed to check whether `hand` contains any winning combinations and return it as a string. When I try to compile class B, which is unfinished right now, I get an error:

```
GamePoker.java:40: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class ArrayList
    location: class GamePoker
    public String checkHand(ArrayList<Card> hand)
```

What might be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Have you imported `ArrayList`?

Comment: Do you use an IDE (like Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.)? They will usually give you a hint right away.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+o on the rescue

Comment: I don't use an IDE, I really should though... And thanks, it was due to not importing `ArrayList`